# Start css animation in iframe when iframe is in viewport

Tags: css, animation, iframe, viewport, google-ads-api

I'm developing HTML5 banner ads for Google AdWords with CSS-animations. Since an ad can only have 30 seconds of animations, the content of the different stages in the animation are often not seen by the users.

Is there a way to find out the viewport of the (cross domain) parent window, so that I can start the animations in my ad's CSS/JS code when it's actually visible to the user ?

Thanks for help!

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules because it's too broad and will attract only opinion based answers (so expect it to be closed). Please, go to the: http://stackoverflow.com/help, then read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @Elias MP - why would you say so? This is a technical question.

Comment: @Gerfried. I thought the question must to provide a MCVE. Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways how you can solve your problem.

For the first, you need to edit the code of your cross-domain parent window. If you can't do that, this wont work (which I guess will be the case for you). You would need to add event listeners and use  [Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

The other way is by using the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). It's exactly the thing you want and designed for exactly your case, but it's currently not very well supported. For compatibility list check out the link or [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=intersectionobserver).
You could implement this with a simple fallback, if it's not available.